# How can I upgrade jython version 2.2.1 to version 2.5?

Tags: java, jython, jython-2.5

On my terminal I have the version 2.2.1 of jython and I would like to upgrade it to the version 2.5.

I tried many different things but it didn't work. Do you know what can I do?

I tried the following ways:

apt-get upgrade

apt-get install jython

and
wget http://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/jython/jython_installer-2.5b3.jar
java -jar jython_installer-2.5b3.jar

Comment: Could you specify what you've tried, otherwise we'll all just sit here and give solutions to things you have already tried :)

Comment: Hmm ok. Does apt output errors? Could you try removing all your jython packages first?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have java installed on your system
2. Download the jar from [sf.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jython/files/jython/2.5.2/jython_installer-2.5.2.jar/download) and then try running the installer in console mode:

   ```
   java -jar jython_installer-2.5.2.jar --console
   ```